# AGIC issues without any changes to Infra

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have AGIC as Ingress for my AKS and without any changes. Seeing below errors:

E0109 08:27:56.481514 1 reflector.go:138] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.0-beta.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.AzureApplicationGatewayRewrite: failed to list *v1beta1.AzureApplicationGatewayRewrite: azureapplicationgatewayrewrites.appgw.ingress.azure.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ingress-appgw-sa" cannot list resource "azureapplicationgatewayrewrites" in API group "appgw.ingress.azure.io" at the cluster scope: Azure does not have opinion for this user.

E0109 09:38:27.684411 1 reflector.go:138] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.0-beta.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.AzureApplicationGatewayRewrite: failed to list *v1beta1.AzureApplicationGatewayRewrite: the server could not find the requested resource (get azureapplicationgatewayrewrites.appgw.ingress.azure.io)

Deleted the POD and recreated but still seeing same error

Comment: Check the roles and cluster roles associated with the ingress-appgw-sa service account. Ensure that these roles include permissions to list, get, and watch resources of type azureapplicationgatewayrewrites in the appgw.ingress.azure.io API group
Check this document- https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/1495

Comment: Hi @Arko,

Where can I find the ingress-appgw-sa? Please can you suggest the above changes how I can do it manually in Azure portal?

Comment: to check the roles and permissions for ingress-appgw-sa 
for checkking service account
`kubectl get serviceaccount ingress-appgw-sa -n kube-system`

To check role binding
`kubectl get roles,rolebindings -n kube-system | grep ingress-appgw-sa`

To inspect the role
`kubectl describe role <role-name> -n kube-system`

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're seeing suggest that the service account `ingress-appgw-sa` used by the Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC) does not have the necessary permissions to list the `AzureApplicationGatewayRewrite` resources in your AKS cluster. To resolve this, you need to ensure that the correct RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) permissions are set for the `ingress-appgw-sa` service account.
First verify your service account
kubectl get serviceaccount ingress-appgw-sa -n kube-system
[image]

list all roles and role bindings in the `kube-system` namespace:

```
kubectl get roles,rolebindings -n kube-system
```

[image]

if you don't see any existing roles or rolebindings for AGIC, you'll need to create them.

Below is an example to enable application gateway ingress controller add-on for an AKS cluster with an existing application gateway.
If you already have an AKS cluster, skip it. if not create a cluster as below-

```
az aks create -n <ClusterName> -g <ResourceGroup> --network-plugin azure --enable-managed-identity --generate-ssh-keys
```

deploy a new application gateway, change the names of myResourceGroup , myPublicIp, myVnet, mySubnet, myApplicationGateway with your choice of names

```
 az network public-ip create -n myPublicIp -g myResourceGroup --allocation-method Static --sku Standard
```

[image]

```
az network vnet create -n myVnet -g myResourceGroup --address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 --subnet-name mySubnet --subnet-prefix 10.0.0.0/24
```

[image]

```
az network application-gateway create -n myApplicationGateway -g myResourceGroup --sku Standard_v2 --public-ip-address myPublicIp --vnet-name myVnet --subnet mySubnet --priority 100
```

[image]

Now enable the AGIC add-on in the AKS cluster

```
appgwId=$(az network application-gateway show -n myApplicationGateway -g myResourceGroup -o tsv --query "id") 
az aks enable-addons -n myCluster -g myResourceGroup -a ingress-appgw --appgw-id $appgwId
```

[image]

If you'd like to use Azure portal to enable AGIC add-on, go to [(https://aka.ms/azure/portal/aks/agic)](https://aka.ms/azure/portal/aks/agic) and navigate to your AKS cluster. From there, go to the Networking tab under your AKS cluster. You'll see an application gateway ingress controller section, with option to enable/disable the ingress controller add-on using the Azure portal.
[image]

Since I've deployed the AKS cluster in its own virtual network and the Application gateway in another virtual network, I'll have to peer the two virtual networks together in order for traffic to flow from the Application gateway to the pods in the cluster.

```
nodeResourceGroup=$(az aks show -n myCluster -g myResourceGroup -o tsv --query "nodeResourceGroup")
aksVnetName=$(az network vnet list -g $nodeResourceGroup -o tsv --query "[0].name")

aksVnetId=$(az network vnet show -n $aksVnetName -g $nodeResourceGroup -o tsv --query "id")
az network vnet peering create -n AppGWtoAKSVnetPeering -g myResourceGroup --vnet-name myVnet --remote-vnet $aksVnetId --allow-vnet-access

appGWVnetId=$(az network vnet show -n myVnet -g myResourceGroup -o tsv --query "id")
az network vnet peering create -n AKStoAppGWVnetPeering -g $nodeResourceGroup --vnet-name $aksVnetName --remote-vnet $appGWVnetId --allow-vnet-access
```

[image]

Done. Now deploying a sample application to the AKS cluster that will use the AGIC add-on for Ingress and connect the application gateway to the AKS cluster.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/master/docs/examples/aspnetapp.yaml

kubectl get ingress
```

[image]
[image]

Reference Documents:
[AGIC on AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing)
[Common Questions and troubleshooting for AGIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-troubleshoot#inspect-kubernetes-installation)